# Como descobrir o HTML gerado pela linha echo $OUTPUT->course_content_header();

Tags: moodle

Estou modificando um tema do moodle, porem eu não consigo encontrar alguns arquivos HTML ou pelo menos entender como eles são criados via backend, tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
            echo $OUTPUT->course_content_header();
            echo $OUTPUT->main_content();
            echo $OUTPUT->course_content_footer();
?>
```

Eu preciso adicionar um elemento dentro do html que uma dessas linhas de código gera, como faço para descobrir no moodle como ele gera esse html e como adicionar esse componente aonde eu quero.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero adicionar um componente HTML dentro do bloco `Visão Geral dos Cursos`, logo acima do texto `Nenhuma informação disponível sobre o curso`

Comment: Esta em lib/outputrenderers.php Mais detalhes em https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=328350#p1320808

Answer (score 1):

Digite o seguinte código: `var_dump($OUTPUT->course_content_header()); die;` para ver a saída da coleção $OUTPUT.

Segue conteúdo do método citado:

`public function course_content_header($onlyifnotcalledbefore = false) {
        global $CFG;
        if ($this->page->course->id == SITEID) {
            // return immediately and do not include /course/lib.php if not necessary
            return '';
        }
        static $functioncalled = false;
        if ($functioncalled && $onlyifnotcalledbefore) {
            // we have already output the content header
            return '';
        }
        require_once($CFG->dirroot.'/course/lib.php');
        $functioncalled = true;
        $courseformat = course_get_format($this->page->course);
        if (($obj = $courseformat->course_content_header()) !== null) {
            return html_writer::div($courseformat->get_renderer($this->page)->render($obj), 'course-content-header');
        }
        return '';
    }`